# How to change C++ standard library implementation in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, libstdc++, libc++

I would like change c++ standard library form microsoft to another which support c++17 standard. I mean swap vs lib with libstdc++ or libc++ Is is possible at all? I have not idea the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, [VS2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/) has some partial support for c++17. It's not only about library but also about compiler support of new features. So, simple answer: better use VS2017 as is, you may even compile with [clang with microsoft codegen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/04/clang-with-microsoft-codegen-in-vs-2015-update-1/).

Comment: i had been using clang in vs, but inteli sense does'nt support some features for instance: fold expression. For the more, MSVC had poor support in compare with gcc or clang: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: @RobertPawlak IntelliSense uses it's own internal compiler to check over syntax, and that cannot be changed.

Comment: @RobertPawlak that page is outdated a bit. Here's link to the current status of what's released, what's released in preview version and what's just around the corner: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/ . No fold expressions yet though. They try to keep intellisense parser on the par with MSVC compiler.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin So, in Your opinion there's no any chance to swap microsoft standard lib with others?

Comment: @RobertPawlak I don't think it would be trivial, but not impossible.

Comment: I think it can be done; not sure how much work that will take though (there might be some MSVC-specific hooks in their STL implementation, and likewise in others'). Why do you want to do that though? C++17 support in MSVC's STL should be reasonably good; better than C++17 support in the compiler. If you want to switch compiler AND library then maybe it is easier to just use clang then? )

Comment: @AndreyTurkin I know, but it will take long a time before microsoft will support c++17 standard perfectly. In my work, i also have been using visual GDB extension, where can i choose platform toolset: LLVM-vs2014_xp. But thats no come up my expectation